# "this" in code does not match with "this" during execution

Tags: knockout.js, typescript

We already know it's useful to do `var self = this` when using Knockout, to avoid issues in event handlers. However, I'm observing weird behaviour within Typescript. Below is a reduced code sample.

```
<i class="icon-edit" data-bind="click: $parent.GetEditForm"></i>
```

```js
export class Foo
{
    public ID: KnockoutObservable<Number>;
}

export class FooEditor
{
    public Items: KnockoutObservableArray<Foo>;

    public GetEditForm(item: Foo, event)
    {
        console.log(this);
        console.log(item);
    }
}
```

According to Visual Studio, `this` is an instance of `FooEditor` and `item` is an instance of `Foo`. However, during execution both `this` and `item` refer to the instance of `Foo`. Is TypeScript wrong here? Or is this part of the magic of Knockout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can preserve the current lexical context in TypeScript by using arrow functions, for example:

```
class Example {
    private name = 'Example';

    constructor() {
        window.setTimeout( () => { alert(this.name); }, 1000);
    }
}
```

In this example, `this.name` will be "Example" because we used an arrow function: `() =>`. If you tried the same with a normal function you would lose the context of `this`:

```
class Example {
    private name = 'Example';

    constructor() {
        window.setTimeout( function() { alert(this.name); }, 1000); // undefined
    }
}
```

Under the hood, TypeScript introduces a variable to store the scope and substitutes it within the function...

```
    var _this = this;
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        alert(_this.name);
    }, 1000);
```

Comment: Unfortunately when using arrow functions you can no longer use overloading. I'm kind of willing to live without overloading for now, I've seen there's activity about the scoping issues on CodePlex.

Answer (score 1):

Its how the javascript works, 'this' is tied to the caller. if you want the 'this' to be parent try this:

```
<i class="icon-edit" data-bind="click: $parent.GetEditForm.bind($parent,$data)"></i>
```

bind will bind 'this' to first parameter which is $parent in your case and then pass $data (foo) as the first parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'll take this over to the TypeScript discussions on CodePlex. `self` always seems to refer to `Window`, accessing a class property needs to be done with `this.Bar` or else it won't compile, but of course during execution, `this` refers to something else again. This is horrible.

Comment: I dont think TypeScript can do anything about it as after all TS gives you javascript, the javascript behaves the way it does.

Comment: The problem is that TypeScript gives me wrong info. Type safety is gone and IntelliSense is wrong. So I could as well write JavaScript at this point. https://typescript.codeplex.com/discussions/449410

Answer (score 0):

i came across the same problem, loosing scope inside callback functions.

I tried the arrow functions, but still didn't was able to maintain scope.

So, after digging enought i came with this solution:

```
   loadObject = () => {
            var mySelf = this;
            Phoria.Util.importGeometryWavefront({
              url: "app/js/models/phoria/teapot.obj",
              scaleTo: 5,
              fnSuccess: function (args) { mySelf.placeObject(mySelf,args) },
             reorder: false,
             center: true
        });
    }


    placeObject  = (mySelf,obj) =>{
        mySelf.entityTeapot= Phoria.Entity.create({
            points: obj.points,
            polygons: obj.polygons,
            style: {
                specular: 0,
                drawmode: "solid",
                shademode: "lightsource",   //gouraud
                fillmode: "inflate"
            }
        });
        mySelf.scene.graph.push(this.entityTeapot);
    };
```

I followed the lead of this answer  [Typescript + Jquery Ajax + this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15662038/typescript-jquery-ajax-this)

But i had some issues using "self" (it points to Window).

In the end it seems to be intercepting the callback call and injecting the scope into it.

Hope it helps,
Renato